# Not allowed to launch 'mailto:' because a user gesture is required

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, href, mailto

I am creating a chrome extension wherein I'd like to email the result.

So this is the UI from Chrome Extension Popup.
[image]

Then this is the `a` for that:

[image]

So basically, the code is

```
<a href={`mailto:{email}`}>email</a>
```

It will open my email app at first click,
[image]

but the second click to email will produce this error:
[image]

What seems to be the problem here? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Not yet.. I cant find any related solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by clicking again while the mail is open.

So, if you doesn't matter extenstion closing when the link is clicked, Try this

```
 <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href={`mailto:{email}`}>mail</a>
```